# Apply a sed command to every column of a specific row

Tags: awk, sed

I have a tab separated file:

```
samplename1/filename1   anotherthing/anotherfile    asdfgh/hjklñ
        2                        3                      4
        5                        6                      7
```

I am trying to remove everything after the `/` just in the header of the file using sed:

```
sed 's/[/].*//' samplenames.txt
```

How can I do this for each column of the file? because right now I am removing everything after the first `/`, but I want to remove just the part of each column after the `/`.

Actual output:

```
samplename1
     2                  3                4
     5                  6                7
```

Desired output:

```
samplename1          anotherthing            asdfgh
    2                     3                    4
    5                     6                    7
```

Comment: `sed -i '1 s,/[^[:space:]]*,,g' samplenames.txt`? See https://ideone.com/Kb99tE

Comment: Yes, this have worked!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With GNU `sed`, you may use

```
sed -i '1 s,/[^[:space:]]*,,g' samplenames.txt
```

With FreeBSD sed, you need to add `''` after `-i`.

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/Kb99tE)

The `-i` option will make `sed` change the file inline. The `1` means only the first line will be modified in the file.

The `s,/[^[:space:]]*,,g` command means that all occurrences of `/` followed with 0 or more non-whitespace chars after it will be removed.

Answer (score 0):

Given:

```
printf "samplename1/filename1\tanotherthing/anotherfile\tasdfgh/hjklñ
2\t3\t4
5\t6\t7" >file # ie, note only one tab between fields...
```

Here is an POSIX awk to do this:

```
awk -F $"\t" 'NR==1{gsub("/[^\t]*",""); print; next} 1' file
```

Prints:

```
samplename1 anotherthing    asdfgh
2   3   4
5   6   7
```

You can get those to line up with the `column` command:

```
awk -F $"\t" 'NR==1{gsub("/[^\t]*",""); print; next} 1' file | column -t
samplename1  anotherthing  asdfgh
2            3             4
5            6             7
```